# How to run Selenium grid in Windows and Mac containers using Docker

Tags: docker, selenium-grid

I have seen a lot of articles showing how to run Selenium distributed tests in Docker containers using Selenium Grid. I guess one of the main advantage of using Selenium Grid is that tests can be run of different OS - browser combinations based on the capabilities specified in the test. My requirement is that I want to execute my tests on Windows and Mac platforms using different browsers. It is possible to achieve this using docker containers?

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried to setup a SeleniumGrid on Windows Container on a Windows 10 machine.

1. Setup Network

> docker network create --driver nat my-net

2. Start the Selenium-Hub

> docker run -d -p **4446**:4444 --net my-net --name selenium-hub
> selenium/hub

3. Start a browser

> docker run -d -P --net my-net -e HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
> selenium/node-chrome-debug

4. Browser Console to view connected browser nodes

   localhost:**4446**/grid/console
5. You can use VCN viewer to connect to this Node

**Official Resource:**

```
*https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium*
```

(Most of the commands/instructions are specific to Linux containers)